# How to Parse large xml files using SAX?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse xml file nearly around 7Mb using SAX, is there any methods available to set the file size or something, Please tell how to do parsing using SAX ?

Answer (score 2):

The point about the SAX parser is that *size shouldn't really matter*. Because it's event driven, the parser only needs to read a little at a time, and send you start/end events as it encounters each XML element. It doesn't build a complete model of the XML in memory (unlike for DOM).

[Here's a tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=29#50616).